# Tkinter/Matplotlib backend conflict causes infinite mainloop

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Consider running the following code (note it is an extremely simplified version to demonstrate the problem):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from tkinter import * #Tkinter if your on python 2

def main():

    fig = plot.figure(figsize=(16.8, 8.0))

    root = Tk()
    w = Label(root, text="Close this and it will hang!")
    w.pack()
    root.mainloop()

    print('Code never reaches this point')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Closing the first window will work fine, but closing the second window causes the code to hang, as `root.mainloop()` causes an infinite loop. This problem is caused by calling `fig = plot.figure(figsize=(16.8, 8.0))`. Does anyone know how to get root to close succesfully after making that matplotlib.pyplot call?

Comment: `pyplot` also starts up it's own mainloop which I suspect is your problem. See http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/ for how to embed mpl in a gui of your choice

Comment: Is there any way to force close a pyplot mainloop? The problem affects all following tkinter windows after the pyplot call, even in different modules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import matplotlib
from tkinter import *

def main():

    fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(16.8, 8.0))

    root = Tk()
    w = Label(root, text="Close this and it will not hang!")
    w.pack()
    root.mainloop()

    print('Code *does* reach this point')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When embedding a matplotlib figure inside a `Tkinter` window, use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` rather than `plt.Figure`.

Comment: My answer still stands -- especially using `matplotlib.figure.Figure` rather than `plt.Figure`. That change alone will make your code work.

Comment: Cool that one line was what I needed, could you explain the backend difference between matplotlib.figure.Figure and plt.Figure as it applies to the mainloop? Thanks!

Comment: `plt.figure` uses a figure manager to wrangle the mainloop/gui ect.  `matplotlib.figure.Figure` is just a `Figure` object and it is your problem to wrangle the gui.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of conflict of matplotlib with Tkinter by "closing" matplotlib plotting (after plotting is finished) before opening a Tkinter window:

```
plt.close()
tk = Tkinter()
...
```