# Why does matplotlib.figure.Figure behave so different than matplotlib.pyplot.figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

A fellow programmer alerted me to a problem where matplotlib.pyplot and Tkinter don't behave well together, as demonstrated by this question [Tkinter/Matplotlib backend conflict causes infinite mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535766/tkinter-matplotlib-backend-conflict-causes-infinite-mainloop)

We changed our code to prevent potential problems as mentioned in the linked question, as follows:

**Old**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
if os.path.isfile('./UI.png'):
    image = plt.imread('./UI.png')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    im = plt.imshow(image)
# The Canvas
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master = master)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, root)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH,expand=YES)
self.canvas.draw()
```

**Intermediate (UI.png not being shown)**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
self.fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(8, 6))
if os.path.isfile('./UI.png'):
    image = matplotlib.image.imread('./UI.png')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.imshow(image)
# The Canvas
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, root)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
self.canvas.draw()
```

The changed code did not display the 'background' image anymore and I have been mostly just trying random things (as I am quite lost in the difference between the two options) to get the figure displaying again. The changes involved switching from `tight_layout` to `set_tight_layout` to avoid a warning, as mentioned on https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1852 . The resulting code is as follows:

**Potential Fix**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
self.fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(8, 6))
background_image = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
if os.path.isfile('./UI.png'):
    image = matplotlib.image.imread('./UI.png')
    background_image.axis('off')
    #self.fig.tight_layout() # This throws a warning and falls back to Agg renderer, 'avoided' by using the line below this one.
    self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    background_image.imshow(image)
# The Canvas
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=master)
self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, root)
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
self.canvas.draw()
```

The question therefore is, why do we need to use a subplot now (using matplotlib.figure.Figure) while before we did not (using matplotlib.pyplot)?

PS: I am sorry if this is a silly question but almost everything that I can find on the subject seems to use the `matplotlib.pyplot` variant. Therefore, I am having trouble finding any good documentation for the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

> The question therefore is, why do we need to use a subplot now (using matplotlib.figure.Figure) while before we did not (using matplotlib.pyplot)?

`subplot` creates an `Axes` object.  You did have one before, but the `pyplot` API "hid" it from you under the covers so you didn't realise it.  You are now trying to use the objects directly, so have to handle it yourself.

#### More detailed reason

The reason you see this behaviour is because of how `matplotlib.pyplot` works.  To quote [the tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) a little:

> `matplotlib.pyplot` is a collection of command style functions that make matplotlib work like MATLAB.... `matplotlib.pyplot` is stateful, in that it keeps track of the current figure and plotting area, and the plotting functions are directed to the current axes

The crucial bit is that `pyplot` is stateful.  It is keeping track of state "under the covers" and hiding the object model from you to some extent.  It also does some implicit things.  So - if you simply call, e.g., `plt.axis()`, under the covers [`pyplot` calls `plt.gca()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L1498) and that in turn [calls `gcf()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L917) which will [return a new figure](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L559), because you haven't set up a figure via `pyplot` yet.  This is true for most calls to `plt.some_function()` - if `pyplot` doesn't have a figure object ***in it's own state*** yet, it will create one.

So, in your intermediate example, you've created your own `Figure` object - fiven it a name `self.fig` (I'm not sure what your class structure is, so I don't know what `self` is, but I'm guessing it's your `tk.Frame` object or something similar).

#### The punchline

`pyplot` ***doesn't know anything about `self.fig`***.  So in your intermediate code, you're calling `imshow()` on the `Figure` object in `pyplot` state, but displaying a different figure (`self.fig`) on your canvas.

The problem is not that you need to use `subplot` as such, but that you need to change the background image on the correct `Figure` object.  The way you've used `subplot` in your potential fix code will do that - although I suggest an alternative below which maybe makes the intent clearer.

#### How to fix

Change

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.imshow(image)
```

to

```
self.fig.set_tight_layout(True)
ax = self.fig.gca() # You could use subplot here to get an Axes object instead
ax.axis('off')
ax.imshow(image)
```

#### A note on root cause: `pyplot` API vs direct use of objects

This a bit of an opinion, but might help.  I tend to use the `pyplot` interface when I need to quickly get things prototyped and want to use one of the fairly standard cases.  Often, that is enough.

As soon as I need to do more complicated things, I start to use the object model directly - maintaining my own named `Figure` and `Axes` objects etc.

Mixing the two is possible, but often confusing.  You've found this with your intermediate solution.  So I recommend doing one or the other.

Comment: Great answer. Which would you argue is better, using the subplot variant (as I stumbled upon) or the `fig.gca()` (as you list in your fix)?

Comment: I'd argue the `gca()` is clearer to read in this case - I always think subplot makes me think there is likely to be more than one.  However, that really is down to personal preference - either is fine.  If you do `print(type(ax))` after the `gca()` you will see its concrete type is actually `AxesSubplot` (a subclass of `Axes`) - exactly the same as returned by `add_subplot()`